# Shading of a plane

Tags: three.js

It is probably a beginner question, but why does the plane appear to be flat? Why is the structure of the plane not visible, only the spikes on the edges?

http://codepen.io/asz/pen/GgXpXW

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 100, 100, 50, 50 );

var vertices = geometry.attributes.position.array;
for ( var i = -1; i < vertices.length; i += 3) {
  vertices[i] = Math.random() * 10;
}

geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( - Math.PI / 2.8 ) );

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0x00ff00, color: 0x00ff00, specular: 0x00ff00, shininess: 30, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );
var ground = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( ground );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do with normals.
add `geometry.computeVertexNormals();`

eg.

```
var vertices = geometry.attributes.position.array;
for ( var i = -1; i < vertices.length; i += 3) {
  vertices[i] = Math.random() * 10;
}
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

Comment: Ah, do I have to recalculate the normals everytime I change something in the geometry?