# Shading on PlaneBufferGeometry in Three.JS

Tags: three.js

I'm generating a random plane that animates movement in the vertices to give a crystalline effect. When I use regular `PlaneGeometry`, shading is not a problem: http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/GJppEX

However, I tried to switch to `PlaneBufferGeometry` to see if I could get better performance, but the shading disappeared.
http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/oXjyJL?editors=001

```
var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(opts.planeSize, opts.planeSize, opts.planeDefinition, opts.planeDefinition),
    planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: 0x555555,
      emissive: 0xdddddd,
      shading: THREE.NoShading
    }),
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial),
    defaultVertices = planeGeometry.attributes.position.clone().array;

  function randomVertices() {
    var vertices = planeGeometry.attributes.position.clone().array;
    for (var i = 0; i <= vertices.length; i += 3) {
      // x
      vertices[i] = defaultVertices[i] + (rand(-opts.variance.x, opts.variance.x));
      // y
      vertices[i + 1] = defaultVertices[i + 1] + (rand(-opts.variance.y, opts.variance.y));
      // z
      vertices[i + 2] = rand(-opts.variance.z, -opts.variance.z);
    }
    return vertices;
  }

  plane.geometry.attributes.position.array = randomVertices();
```

As I saw suggested [in this answer to 'Shading on a plane'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28899589/1012919), I tried:

```
plane.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

On render, I have tried all of the following attributes for the geometry to make sure it's updating the normals & vertices, like I've done on the working example with `PlaneGeometry`:

```
plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
plane.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
plane.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
plane.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
plane.geometry.normalizeNormals();
```

What has happened to the shading? Can I bring it back on a `PlaneBufferGeometry` mesh, or do I need to stick with `PlaneGeometry`?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not very much familiar with PlaneBufferGeometry, but in general, the difference between geometry and bufferGeometry in three is that the first one has a structure, the second one are just buffers, often triangle soup rather than indexed. With that being said, traversing a structure, that knows what belongs to a vertex, what belongs to a face, where are the neighbors etc, allows you to compute normals dynamically with ease. A triangle soup does not.

Comment: @pailhead It's strange that THREE.js is so insistent on using the `PlaneBufferGeometry` if it's not going to provide similar visual results. At any rate, I was under the impression that `computeVertexNormals` or a similar function would allow it to be shaded.

Comment: i find that warning message annoying myself. I just havent taken a proper look at planeBufferGeometry, i wouldn't be surprised if it's a bit smarter than other bufferGeometry, since a plane is something that is so often used. But then again, if it has the javascript mesh structure, it's not going to be more memory efficient :)

Comment: You might want to look a bit into "morphing" and "skinning" to get a better idea of what is going on. When you create a plane, it has normals (it's the same normal for every face / vertex) when you modify this plane, and create something resembling a landscape, some faces, and some vertices (if not all) will have different normals. There are different ways of doing this. With such a regular topology (grid) you could even pass this info to the shader, and have it dynamically computed on the gpu.